# Vector field reconstruction

Tags: vector

I have a time series (a sequence of 2D points), and I would like to reconstruct a vector field that contains this path.

Here is my data (each successive point is sampled 1 second later):

```
data = CloudGet[
   "https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/user-e9c7e0a8-2832-4d10-9d87-\
2bdc3ad8ae5b/data"];
```

[image]

Are there any built functions that can do this?

Comment: You want to reconstruct a vector field from a test particle?

Comment: That's right, I would like to plot the vector field the particle is moving through

Comment: I am also not completely sure what you want to achieve. Do you want to obtain a continuous function that maps the time `t` onto a 2D vector, i.e. `t -> (x(t), y(t))` and you supply the discrete points? So you want to do some kind of interpolation?

Comment: I assume it's not a gradient vectorfield? Otherwise the solution would be selfevident.

Comment: Is there an equation of motion for the particle?